# Merged two bash scripts now one doesn't work

Tags: database, bash, sed

I decided to take a script of mine that I wrote and a script I found here and merge scripts together so that a friend wouldn't have to run two scripts. As he is new to bash it's a confusing file type and format so I'm trying to make his life a little easier.

Basically when we scrape accounts we get a list of IDs that come with a little bit of code at the top and the bottom of the list, so I have this script to remove that bit of code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
cat $FILE | sed '1,7d' | sed -n -e :a -e '1,9!{P;N;D;};N;ba' > edited/$FILE
```

and the second script I use I ended up editing so that the line came after the link (he wants links to the accounts and not who they followed)

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
endname=$2
while read line; do
   echo "$line  | User Follows/followed $handle"
done < $FILE > Appended/$endname.txt
```

I edited this file so that it would loop so that he can do this to several files at once:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo what file do you wish to remove info lines from
    read -e FILE
    echo where do you want the new file to be located
    read -e endlocation
    echo what would you like the new file to be named
    read filename
    cat $FILE | sed '1,7d' | sed -n -e :a -e '1,9!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
    while read line; do
            echo "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=$line"
    done < $FILE | uniq > $endlocation/$filename
    rm $FILE
done
```

The problem is that the two scripts work 100% perfectly separate but once I combine them, one, or the other, will fail to work. Right now sed doesn't work and so i had the idea that i would output the sed and then reassign the FILE variable to the file that sed output, but even then sed hadn't done it's job. Is there something blaringly obvious that I just completely missed? A friend and I have looked at this script for hours each trying too figure out what is happening, or not happening is the better way to put it. 
As always, thank you for any help!

****EDIT:**** 
Here is a sample input file (you can make a twitter follower scrape yourself at www.dd-css.com):

```
{
 "username": "testy", 
 "created_time": {
  "$date": 1461085587225
 }, 
 "data": {
  "followers": [
   721008887751688192, 
   281667578, 
   702184946996224000, 
   3217284865, 
   722068840314634240, 
   2885989935, 
   718119030083698690, 
   4848801485, 
   714443675665887232, 
   4880594986, 
   4166478021, 
   722420986369466368, 
   3232181141, 
   722079476553752576, 
   722417819405553666, 
   3363234395, 
   722111118781468673, 
   3150091062, 
   719798662625419264, 
   388415906, 
   722038039023849473, 
   720509286149971968, 
   720535522347773953, 
   709060581224009728, 
   722133050629480448, 
   721984368072388608, 
   720066765829644288, 
   722377228382773248, 
   4874218565, 
   4900522317, 
   721954174116708352, 
   712480939427946496, 
   388526427, 
   712931529924677632, 
   721964884267651073
  ]
 }, 
 "qname": "Twitter Friends & Followers", 
 "parameters": {
  "friends_limit": 0, 
  "screen_name": "Aminov274", 
  "followers_limit": 1000
 }
}
```

Here Is what the output file needs to look like for my friend to be able to use:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721008887751688192
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=281667578
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=702184946996224000
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3217284865
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722068840314634240
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=2885989935
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=718119030083698690
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4848801485
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=714443675665887232
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4880594986
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4166478021
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722420986369466368
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=323218114
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722079476553752576
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722417819405553666
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3363234395
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722111118781468673
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3150091062
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=719798662625419264
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=388415906
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722038039023849473
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=720509286149971968
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=720535522347773953
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=709060581224009728
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722133050629480448
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721984368072388608
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=720066765829644288
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722377228382773248
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4874218565
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4900522317
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721954174116708352
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=712480939427946496
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=388526427
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=712931529924677632
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721964884267651073
```

Comment: Did you try `bash -x scriptname`  to get a trace?  Is the `sed` meant to write to a file?  (BTW, there is no need for `cat`, `sed` takes a filename as a parameter).

Comment: No I did not...don't even know how that would work. :-/ and yea I just got used to writing cat before sed before I figured that out and ill do it every now and again.

Comment: Try it.  It displays (on stderr) the lines after expansion.

Comment: I think you should compare the `sed` in your original script to the new one.  Originally you were redirecting it to a file.

Comment: It says it's running the sed commands...

Comment: the original sed and this sed match perfectly. (Besides removing the output to separate file part.)

Comment: You don't seem to be connecting the stdout of the cat/sed/sed line to the stdin of the read line. Missing `|` at end of cat line? (Also remove `< $FILE` from the `done` line of course.)

Comment: Where is the output from the `sed` supposed to go?

Comment: the original sed just made removed the lines and placed the document in a different directory with the same name. this sed i didnt want to make an extra file because i have a read command right there

Comment: Ill remove the < $FILE from done, i think there was a reason i had it in there for the other script but i cant remember, either way it's working now and i havent changed anything to the actual script, i have no idea what changed

Comment: @123 it removes the final 9 lines from the document.

Comment: @Matt You can use head instead of the sed command `head -n -9`, which is easier to read and quicker.

Comment: @123 I will update that, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you want to hear but what you currently have is very inefficient and fragile and should be replaced because while it can be made robust doing so will make the code very complicated and it'll still be extremely slow. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some background but that actually only covers part of the story - there are other ways in which your script can/will fail given various combinations of the contents of your input file, environment settings, and even the contents of the directory you execute it from.

You need to replace this:

```
cat $FILE | sed '1,7d' | sed -n -e :a -e '1,9!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
while read line; do
        echo "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=$line"
done < $FILE | uniq > $endlocation/$filename
rm $FILE
```

with this:

```
awk 'script' "$FILE" > "$endlocation/$filename" &&
rm "$FILE"
```

where `script` will be a concise, robust, efficient (orders of magnitude faster) script to do whatever your seds+loop currently do. If you edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output we can help you write `script`.

Given your posted sample input/output it looks like this is what you need:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS="[,[:space:]]+" }
    /\]/ { inBlock=0 }
    inBlock { print "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=" $2 }
    /"followers"/ { inBlock=1 }
' file
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721008887751688192
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=281667578
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=702184946996224000
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3217284865
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722068840314634240
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=2885989935
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=718119030083698690
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4848801485
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=714443675665887232
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4880594986
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4166478021
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722420986369466368
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3232181141
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722079476553752576
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722417819405553666
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3363234395
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722111118781468673
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=3150091062
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=719798662625419264
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=388415906
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722038039023849473
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=720509286149971968
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=720535522347773953
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=709060581224009728
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722133050629480448
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721984368072388608
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=720066765829644288
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=722377228382773248
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4874218565
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=4900522317
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721954174116708352
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=712480939427946496
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=388526427
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=712931529924677632
https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=721964884267651073
```

Here is exactly what your shell script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo what file do you wish to remove info lines from
    read -e FILE
    echo where do you want the new file to be located
    read -e endlocation
    echo what would you like the new file to be named
    read filename
    awk '
        BEGIN { FS="[,[:space:]]+" }
        /\]/ { inBlock=0 }
        inBlock && !seen[$2]++ { print "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=" $2 }
        /"followers"/ { inBlock=1 }
    ' "$FILE" > "$endlocation/$filename" &&
    rm "$FILE"
done
```

I added the `!seen[$2]++` as I just noticed the pipe to `uniq` in your original (which would not have worked btw since your input is unsorted but what I have above in the awk script WILL work).

Comment: I'm happy to receive critiques! I have updated the post with the information you requested.

Comment: I posted an awk script that I THINK is what you're looking for. If not then please edit your question to provide more information on your requirements and in what way this is not doing what you want.

Comment: I can't get your command to run, don't know if I'm to stupid to figure out, here is the error i get. `./test.sh: line 6: awk
    BEGIN { FS="[,[:space:]]+" }
    /\]/ { inBlock=0 }
    inBlock { print "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=" $2 }
    /"followers"/ { inBlock=1 }
: No such file or directory`

Comment: I updated my answer to at the end show exactly what your modified script should look like.

Comment: copy pasted your script and its still giving me that error.

Comment: I'm missing a space between `awk` and `'`. I fixed that now. Please try again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Yes it works, I'm busy looking at the awk commands so that I can fully comprehend what is going on inside the script. Thank you for this again.

Comment: You're welcome. The difference between this and what you had before is that this will run an order of magnitude faster, will reproduce your input as-is in the output instead of mangling it given some input values, will work as-is on all POSIX systems, will not be affected by environment variable settings, and will be unaffected by the contents of the directory you execute it from. Feel free to ask questions and if you'd like to learn awk I highly recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins (the provider of GNU awk).

Answer (score 0):

You've bypassed the 2 `sed`s by having the `cat` and the `while read` read from the *same* file (without outputting any intermediate file). Do this instead:

```
cat $FILE |
  sed '1,7d' |
  sed -n -e :a -e '1,9!{P;N;D;};N;ba' |
  while read line; do
        echo "https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=$line"
  done |
  uniq > $endlocation/$filename
```

Comment: What you say is true but that will still fail in cryptic and potentially disastrous ways given various input file contents, environment settings, directory you run the script from, will not be portable to other UNIX systems, will corrupt the output file given some input file contents, will be immensely slow and can cause the original input file to be removed when no output file has been produced. Oh, and it has a UUOC. Don't do it. @Matt Edit your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output if you'd like to see how to do this the right way.

Comment: It works for his apparently-strictly-structured input. And "feeding him a fish" doesn't motivate him to "learn to fish" (develop better techniques himself).

Comment: When someone asks why they aren't catching any fish by throwing rocks at them, you don't tell them to throw bigger rocks, you show them how to use a fishing pole. I would hope that showing the OP how to use an awk script for this job will motivate him to learn to use awk for his future text manipulation jobs instead of bigger shell scripts.

Comment: @EdMorton The failure of the original script was not due to any of the concerns about user input or current directory etc.. So the "bigger rock" metaphor is off. My (pedagogical) counter-concern is about "over-answering".

Comment: I completely understand where you're coming from but what the OP is doing is 100% the wrong approach (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)) so why help him do THAT in a way that's a little bit better in some way but still 100% the wrong approach rather than trying to open his eyes to the right approach? That's my thought process anyway, others are free to disagree of course.

Comment: Had no idea this was going on, I agree with both of you. I don't think the answer should always be flat out given, but I'd also like to know what is going on inside the code, with the previous code I knew everything that was happening and that's why they worked separately. I'm new to text manipulation in scripts so i have heard of awk but the commands for awk were not as straightforward (for a noob) as sed in my mind.

Comment: @Matt to use awk you need to know that there is an implicit `while read line` loop, each script has a basic `<condition> { <action to execute when condition is true> }` syntax and awk populates about a dozen built-in variables as the lines are read to hold the common values required to manipulate text (e.g. line numbers, count of fields, values of each field). Once you grasp that, awk is just a much simplified version of C highly optimised to manipulate text. See http://awk.info/?doc/tip/sedInAwk.html for info on those variables and some examples of how to do some common sed operations in awk.